# Where is Laravel model's static where function?! How does Laravel do that?

Tags: laravel

I have an Eloquent model and I'd like to create some shortcut functions for specific models, like maybe `User::tall()` instead of writing `User::where("height", ">", 185)`. But I want them to be static as well as non-static methods, so that I can also call `$user->where('is_active', '=', '1')->tall()`.

Is there a way I can do that?
I can see that Laravel somehow manages to do that, cause where can be called from both contexts. I've looked through the code but I can only find an object method.

Comment: You are looking for [Facade](http://laravel.com/docs/facades) but maybe not appropriate for a model, IMO.

Comment: Query Scopes is the way to go in Laravel, like mattiashallstrom said below

Answer (score 4):

I think query scope is what you are looking for:
http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#query-scopes

```
public function scopeTall($query)
{
    return $query->where('height', '>', 185);
}
```

You can also specify parameters to a query scope, for example:

```
public function scopeTall($query, $height = 185)
{
    return $query->where('height', '>', $height);
}
```

Scope queries are chainable.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with something like  this?

```
class YourClassModel extends Eloquent
{
     public static function tall() 
     {
         // Return the result of your query
         return ...;
     }
}
```

Comment: In your classmodel (who extends from Eloquent) try adding the static method tall(), like the code in the answer.

Comment: You know this will work? If yes, how? Cause if you're inside a static context, the code will have to be different.

Comment: You can use static::where() or $this->where() and it'll work the same, depending on the context.

Answer (score 1):

Just write a new static method on your user class

```
class User extends Eloquent {
    public static function tall() {
        return User::where("height", ">", 185);
    }
}
```

Then access it elsewhere

```
$users = User::tall()->get();
```

If you make sure that you don't include that `->get()` call in your method and instead include it when you call the method (as above) then since the query builder is returned you should be able to add other where statements to it before calling `get()`

```
$users = User::tall()->where("is_active", "=", 1)->get();
```